# Replace a string without changing case?

Tags: substitute

Due to a quirk in the domain-specific language I am working with, I frequently face the task of (selectively, not globally) replacing `term` or `TERM` with `word` or `WORD`, respectively.

This means, I search case-insensitively for `term`, and want to replace that with `word` *while keeping the uppercase / lowercase of the original `term` intact*.

Since checking the whole of `term` for *consistent* upper-/lowercase would be difficult and is not really necessary, I would settle for uppercase / lowercase of `word` / `WORD` being decided on the first letter of `term`.

How could I achieve this?

Comment: Note about the "selectively" for those who don't know it: Just add `c` to the end of the substitution statements below, and Vim will ask you about every single match.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Michaels Geddes' plugin [keepcase](https://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=6) ([GitHub](https://github.com/vim-scripts/keepcase.vim)) has all you need:

```
:%SubstituteCase/\cterm/word/g
```

Other syntax elements from `:substitute` are also supported.

Comment: Brilliant... this will *significantly* speed up things for me. I also notice that I no longer ask "*can* this be done", but only "*how* to do it". Seems I've finally "arrived" at Vim. :-D

Answer (score 21):

This can be handled by the `:Subvert` from the [abolish plugin](https://github.com/tpope/vim-abolish/#substitution):

> One time I had an application with a domain model called "facility"
>   that needed to be renamed to "building". So, a simple search and
>   replace, right?
>
> ```
> :%s/facility/building/g
> ```
>
> Oh, but the case variants!
>
> ```
> :%s/Facility/Building/g
> :%s/FACILITY/BUILDING/g
> ```
>
> Wait, the plural is more than "s" so we need to get that too!
>
> ```
> :%s/facilities/buildings/g
> :%s/Facilities/Buildings/g
> :%s/FACILITIES/BUILDINGS/g
> ```
>
> Abolish.vim has your back. One command to do all six, and you can
>   repeat it with & too!
>
> ```
> :%Subvert/facilit{y,ies}/building{,s}/g
> ```

Comment: [Vimcasts](http://vimcasts.org/) episode: [Supercharged substitution with :Subvert](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/supercharged-substitution-with-subvert/)